# Cancel mat-slide-toggle twice changes toggle status

Tags: angular, angular-material

Canceling mat-slide-toggle twice changes the toggle status.

html:

```
<mat-slide-toggle (change)="change($event)" [checked]="checked">To-pay</mat-slide-toggle>
<p>{{checked}}</p>
```

ts:

```
change(e) {
      if (confirm("Are you sure")) {
        this.checked = !this.checked;
        console.log("toggle")
      }
      else {
        e.source.checked = !(e.source.checked);
        console.log("toggle should not change if I click the cancel button")
      }
  }
```

This is [stackbliz sample.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-79yf7m-dbsp1f?file=app%2Fslide-toggle-overview-example.ts)

Click the toggle and cancel on confirmation window, the toggle remains unchecked.
Click the toggle again and cancel again, the toggle should remain unchecked, but becomes checked.

Why the toggle becomes checked on cancelling twice? How should I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line `e.source.checked = !(e.source.checked);` with this `e.source.checked = this.checked;`.

The problems comes from the `e.source.checked` element. As MoxxiManagarm told you, you emit a change before requesting the user, so the `e.source.checked` value will change every time you click on it, even if you have a confirm modal.

First time the value will change to `true` and you add to `e.source.checked` the opposite, which is `false`, as wanted. But second time it will change to `false`, and by setting the value with the opposite again, you change it to `true`, which is not the wanted result.

Answer (score 0):

By reacting on `change` event you actually change the value before you ask the user. I doubt that this is what you really want. Please consider reacting on `click` event instead and change the value after user confirmed

```
<mat-slide-toggle (click)="change($event)" [checked]="checked">To-pay</mat-slide-toggle>
<p>{{checked}}</p>
```

```
change(e) {
      if (confirm("Are you sure")) {
        e.source.checked = !(e.source.checked);
      }
  }
```